# Изменение или создание своего контрола

Tags: c#, wpf

Добрый день. Внезапно понадобился листбокс, но не простой, а с доп свойствами, хотелось бы, чтобы он имел примерно такую структуру:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть я хочу сделать листбокс, в котором будет список объектов, у которых будет какой-то текст, картинки и тд и чтобы это все отображалось в одной строке. Какими способами можно это сделать? Желательно не сильно муторными. Спасибо

Comment: Укажите хотя бы, что вы используете. ASP.NET Forms/WinForms/WPF.

Comment: WinForms, но впринципе можно и в впф покопаться

Comment: На wpf несложно. на винформс - муторный хардкор

Comment: Ну пусть будет wpf, я не знаю все равно, как это там сделать

Comment: ну сейчас состряпаю примерчик

Comment: @Сергей Смотря что считать муторным хардкором. В целом согласен, на WPF немного проще, стили, шаблоны и все такое. В формах - UserControl как основа Item-ов списка и FlowLayoutPanel для отображения списка Item-ов. Если не пытаться сделать "резиновую" верстку на формах, то тоже не слишком муторно, а если попытаться - то это уже не "муторный хардкор", а просто полный П.

Comment: Дополнительных свойств будет строго заданное количество заранее известных типов или могут быть разные типы в произвольном количестве? Так-то в WinForms легко нарисовать что угодно в `ListBox` в событии `DrawItem`.

Comment: Как вариант, можно взять `DataGridView` с колонками нужных типов (для изображений, текста и т. п.) Можно и резиновую вёрстку реализовать, с помощью `TableLayoutPanel/FlowLayoutPanel`.

Comment: Если нужен WinForm контрол, которому можно задавать эти свойства в режиме дизайнера, задавая мышкой в окошке Properties, то смотрите книгу Павла Агурова "Разработка компонентов в MS Visual Studio".

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не надо резиновую на FLP, тут уже 2 или 3 вопроса (с ответами) висит в стиле "как заставить работать FLP правильно?". Там костыль костылем погоняет. Можно - да, нужно - нет, лучше WPF сразу., хотя бы и хостом, если приложение в целом на формах.

Comment: Да зачем насиловать пованивающую технологию - ладно если надо состряпать по быстрому какую-нибудь типовую форму из стандартных контролов - то тут да, еще есть смысл, а так... винформс пора уже отправить на покой.

Comment: Впрочем WPF тоже требует реформ. Вон по авалонии видно, что можно xaml много где упростить и улучшить.

Comment: @Сергей рано еще им на покой =) альтернатив для быстрых "не пользовательских" интерфейсов нет, WPF слишком тяжел, а консоль не всегда достаточно презентативна. Промежутка кроме форм нет и, скорее всего, уже не будет. Другой вопрос, что не надо их тащить туда, где заказчик хочет "красиво"

Comment: На счет того, что WPF тяжел - спорно. Ну да ладно. Сойдемся на этом)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простой пример на WPF с биндингами коих в инете полно.

XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ListBoxViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="ListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="50" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
                <TextBlock Width="200" Text="{Binding Text}" />
                <Button Content="Удалить"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                        Command="{Binding ElementName=ListBox, Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

ViewModel и Model:

```
public class ListBoxItemModel
{
    public ListBoxItemModel(string imageSource, string text)
    {
        ImageSource = imageSource;
        Text = text;
    }

    public string ImageSource { get; }
    public string Text { get; }
}

public class ListBoxViewModel
{
    public ListBoxViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ListBoxItemModel>
        {
            new ListBoxItemModel("http://www.playground.ru/img/ui/playground-main-logo-new.png", "someText1"),
            new ListBoxItemModel("http://www.playground.ru/img/ui/playground-main-logo-new.png", "someText2")
        };
        DeleteCommand = new Prism.Commands.DelegateCommand<ListBoxItemModel>
            (item => this.Items.Remove(item));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ListBoxItemModel> Items { get; }
    public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; }
}
```

Comment: Забыли упомянуть что ему еще призму для этого тащить надо - не кажется что ему еще рановато?))

Comment: Да, забыл.)) Но если подумать не трудно найти исходники DelegateCommand<T> в инете, и не нужно тащить призм коре.

Answer (score 0):

Не очень красиво и на скорую руку, но вполне рабочий пример. Итак, сперва нужно создать некоторые вспомогательные классы для реализации `MVVM` паттерна - без него сам не хожу в WPF и вам не советую, так что не пугайтесь - часть всей этой простыни из разряда - один раз вставил и забыл. Так же можно использовать какой-либо `MVVM`-фреймворк - где все это (И даже больше) есть, но я считаю, что для начала лучше в рукопашную...

"База" для `ViewModel` - `ViewModelBase.cs`:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            handler?.Invoke(this, e);
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

Два класса команд (с параметром и без - целиком стащил с какого-то сайта побыстрому):

```
   public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
    {
        #region Fields

        readonly Action<T> _execute;
        readonly Predicate<T> _canExecute;

        #endregion // Fields

        #region Constructors

        public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute)
            : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute)
        {
            _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }
        #endregion // Constructors

        #region ICommand Members

        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute?.Invoke((T)parameter) ?? true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute((T)parameter);
        }

        #endregion // ICommand Members
    }

    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        #region Fields

        readonly Action<object> _execute;
        readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

        #endregion // Fields

        #region Constructors

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
            : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }
        #endregion // Constructors

        #region ICommand Members

        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }

        #endregion // ICommand Members
    }
```

Приступаем. Нам нужно окно где всё отображать. Запихиваем в `MainWindow.xaml` примерно такой `xaml`-код:

```
<Window
    x:Class="WPFApplication1.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="{Binding Title}"
    d:DesignHeight="388.602"
    d:DesignWidth="485.968"
    ResizeMode="CanResize"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <ListView
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ElementList}"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Image
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Height="60"
                            Source="{Binding ImageUri}" />

                        <TextBlock
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.RemoveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">Удалить</Button>
                            <Button Command="{Binding SelectCommand}">Выбрать</Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

К нему прилагается вью модель:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _title;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { _title = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Element> ElementList { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ElementList = new ObservableCollection<Element>();
    }


    private RelayCommand<Element> _removeCommand;

    public RelayCommand<Element> RemoveCommand => _removeCommand ??
                                                 (_removeCommand = new RelayCommand<Element>(element =>
                                                 {
                                                     ElementList.Remove(element);
                                                 }));
}
```

Далее нужна вьюмодель для элементов списка:

```
public class Element : ViewModelBase
    {
        private string _title;
        private Uri _imageUri;

        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set
            {
                _title = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private RelayCommand _selectCommand;

        public RelayCommand SelectCommand => _selectCommand ??
                                            (_selectCommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
                                            {
                                                MessageBox.Show(Title, "Вы выбрали");
                                            }));

        public Uri ImageUri
        {
            get { return _imageUri; }
            set
            {
                _imageUri = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public Element(string title)
        {
            Title = title;
        }
    }
```

Далее нам нужно все это связать. Идем в `App.xaml.cs` и прописываем в `OnStartap`:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            var mainVm = new MainViewModel {Title = "Главное окно"};
            mainVm.ElementList.Add( new Element("1") {ImageUri =new Uri(@"http://steshka.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/cifra_1_2.jpg") }); 
            mainVm.ElementList.Add(new Element("два") { ImageUri = new Uri(@"http://www.raskraska.ru/zifra_digital/img/dva_yellow.gif") });
            mainVm.ElementList.Add(new Element("Третий элемент") { ImageUri = new Uri(@"http://izgotovlenie-trafaretov.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/trafaret-cifra-3-tip1.jpg") });
            var mw = new MainWindow {DataContext = mainVm};

            mw.Show();
            base.OnStartup(e);
        }
```

В принципе если я ничего не забыл - все должно заработать.